# Append column to an array in a PySpark dataframe

Tags: arrays, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, append

I have a Dataframe containing 2 columns

```
| VPN    | UPC             |
+--------+-----------------+
| 1      | [4,2]           |
| 2      | [1,2]           |
| null   | [4,7]           |
```

I need a result column with the values of VPN column (string) appended to the UPC column (array). The result should look something like this:

```
| result |
+--------+
| [4,2,1]|
| [1,2,2]|
| [4,7,] |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use [`concat`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat) + [`array`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array). First use `array` to convert `VPN` column to an array type, then concatenate the two array columns with `concat` method:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, [4, 2]), (2, [1, 2]), (None, [4, 7])], ['VPN', 'UPC'])

df.show()
+----+------+
| VPN|   UPC|
+----+------+
|   1|[4, 2]|
|   2|[1, 2]|
|null|[4, 7]|
+----+------+

df.selectExpr('concat(UPC, array(VPN)) as result').show()
+---------+
|   result|
+---------+
|[4, 2, 1]|
|[1, 2, 2]|
|  [4, 7,]|
+---------+
```

Or more pythonic:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import array, concat

df.select(concat('UPC', array('VPN')).alias('result')).show()
+---------+
|   result|
+---------+
|[4, 2, 1]|
|[1, 2, 2]|
|  [4, 7,]|
+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Since **Spark 3.4+** you can use [array_append](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_append.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_append):

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, [4, 2]), (2, [1, 2]), (None, [4, 7])], ['VPN', 'UPC'])
df.show()
# +----+------+
# | VPN|   UPC|
# +----+------+
# |   1|[4, 2]|
# |   2|[1, 2]|
# |null|[4, 7]|
# +----+------+

df = df.select(F.array_append('UPC', F.col('VPN')).alias('result'))
df.show()
# +------------+
# |      result|
# +------------+
# |   [4, 2, 1]|
# |   [1, 2, 2]|
# |[4, 7, null]|
# +------------+
```